# Println! causes OpenGL program to not work?

Tags: opengl, rust, glfw, rust-cargo

I am currently developing a simple program in rust to draw a colored triangle to the screen. I followed the [instructions from OpenGL](https://open.gl/drawing). My program was working fine and the triangle rendered as expected:

[image]

After that I tried abstracting the code: The `VAO`, `VBO` and the `ShaderProgram` became a struct that handled binding, attaching the shaders and so on. That worked. Now to the problem:

When I tried to abstract the Attributes I ran into a problem. I added those two methods to the `ShaderProgram` struct, that should handle the enabling of attributes without having to hardcode things like the stride or the pointer at which position in the vector the attribute starts.

```rust
pub fn add_attribute(&mut self, name: &'a str, length: i32) {
    let mut props = VertexAttributeProps::new(name, length);
    self.attributes.push(props);
}
pub fn apply_attributes(&self) {
    const GL_FLOAT_SIZE: i32 = mem::size_of::<gl::types::GLfloat>() as i32;
    let stride = self
        .attributes
        .iter()
        .fold(0, |prev, attr| prev + attr.length)
        * GL_FLOAT_SIZE;

    let mut current_pos: i32 = 0;
    for attr_options in self.attributes.iter() {
        // println!("{:?}", current_pos);
        unsafe {
            let attribute = VertexAttribute::new(
                location,
                attr_options.length,
                gl::FLOAT,
                gl::FALSE,
                stride,
                (current_pos * GL_FLOAT_SIZE) as *const c_void,
            );
            attribute.enable();
        }
        current_pos = current_pos + attr_options.length;
    }
}
```

With that I wanted to add my attributes like this:

```rust
shader_program.add_attribute("position", 2);
shader_program.add_attribute("color", 3);
shader_program.apply_attributes();
```

instead of this nasty block:

```rust
let posAttrib: GLuint;
unsafe {
    posAttrib = gl::GetAttribLocation(
        shader_program.program_handle,
        "position".as_ptr() as *const i8,
    ) as u32;
    gl::EnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    gl::VertexAttribPointer(
        posAttrib,
        2,
        gl::FLOAT,
        gl::FALSE,
        5 * mem::size_of::<gl::types::GLfloat>() as i32,
        0 as *const c_void,
    )
}

let colAttrib: GLuint;
unsafe {
    colAttrib =
        gl::GetAttribLocation(shader_program.program_handle, "color".as_ptr() as *const i8)
            as u32;
    gl::EnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
    gl::VertexAttribPointer(
        colAttrib,
        3,
        gl::FLOAT,
        gl::FALSE,
        5 * mem::size_of::<gl::types::GLfloat>() as i32,
        (2 * mem::size_of::<gl::types::GLfloat>()) as *const c_void,
    )
}
```

But that did not work.

So I tried debugging. (Yes, the source of the bug lies in this code, I have tested that). I tried comparing the nasty code with my abstraction. So I added this `println!` to the nasty code:

```rust
let posAttrib: GLuint;
unsafe {
    posAttrib = gl::GetAttribLocation(
        shader_program.program_handle,
        "position".as_ptr() as *const i8,
    ) as u32;

    // ???????
    println!("{}", posAttrib);
    // ???????

    gl::EnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    gl::VertexAttribPointer(
        posAttrib,
        2,
        gl::FLOAT,
        gl::FALSE,
        5 * mem::size_of::<gl::types::GLfloat>() as i32,
        0 as *const c_void,
    )
}
```

and the triangle stopped rendering. Removing it and the triangle is back. How can a simple `println` be so harmful?  Is it some kind of timing issue where the `println!` takes to long and everything somehow breaks?

Comment: What is `gl`? What crate defines it?

Comment: Those are my dependencies: gl = "0.14.0"
glfw = "0.51.0"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior. Rust string literals are not null-terminated as [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml) expects. So there's an out-of-bounds read until who knows where.

You'd need to use `"position\0"` or [`CString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html) to fix that.